# Jetty: set up general host

Tags: java, jetty, virtualhost, host, karaf

How can i force Jetty to open all deployed webapps starting from specific virtual host like `test.localhost:8080/myapp` instead of `localhost:8181/myapp`?

Here's snippet from jetty.xml:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <Set name="host">
                    <Property name="jetty.host"/>
               </Set>
                <Set name="port">
                    <Property name="jetty.port" default="8181"/>
                </Set>
                ...
```

... i tried to play with `jetty.host` value but still no success. :(

How to?

Comment: Is the question about virtualhost configuration? or forced redirect to `http://test.localhost`? or about only listening on `test.localhost:8080`?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, it's about listening on `test.localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To LISTEN on a specific network interface, you specify that interface either via its IP address (IPv4 or IPv6) or its hostname.

Since this is a variant of localhost / loopback, then using IP address would be best.

Eg:

```
$ grep localhost /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.1.0   test.localhost
```

Yes, those hosts are on different IPs, intentionally (and valid for the loopback interface).

You could then setup the connector, using the jetty-distribution, for `test.localhost:8080` by using the command line (this is jetty 9 syntax)

```
$ java -jar /path/to/start.jar jetty.host=127.0.1.0 jetty.port=8080
```

You can also put those command line options into your `${jetty.base}/start.ini` as separate lines.

```
$ grep -E "jetty\.(host|port)" /path/to/my.base/start.ini
jetty.host=127.0.1.0
jetty.port=8080
```

Once jetty is started, you can see what interface it is listening on

```
$ netstat -tlnp | grep 8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp4       0      0 127.0.1.0:8080          :::*         LISTEN      14480/java
```

Comment: This is not working for me, when I do this I can still see: ```tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:554           :::*                    LISTEN      30813/java``` and I want jetty 9.1.5 to use ONLY IPv4. Any ideas?