# Karaf: how to configure virtual hosts

Tags: java, jetty, virtual, host, karaf

How to set virtual hosts in Karaf?

Karaf has embedded Jetty, so i made `context.xml` with below content and have put this to `/etc` folder:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/testWAB_war.war</Set>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>test.localhost</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

... but `test.localhost:8181` brings to me `404`.

Instructions in documentation about config file's location are unclear for me, could you tell me what did i wrong?

I think its about cfg file's location...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jetty: set up general host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326436/jetty-set-up-general-host)

Comment: @Justin, are you ok?

Comment: embedded jetty setups traditionally do not use xml based deployment configuration files, thats the realm of the start.jar and jetty-deploy features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Karaf the entire quest is a bit more complicated. You need to name connectors and then use pax-web speciffic manifest header to bind your module to it. More detailed description in blog post: http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2013/01/bind-certain-web-applications-to-specific-httpconnectors/